# Firefox 31 Web Console Layout

Tags: firefox, web-console

[image: Firefox Web Console Screenshot]Firefox 31 has changed my web console layout and I can't find the option to change it back.  Being that I have a widescreen monitor I prefer the console to the right.  When I select an array/object to view it opens it in a split as expected, but ever since the update I can't get the split to stack them vertically so they can use more width.  Am I just not seeing this option?

Update: For Firefox up to v33 use this plugin, for 34+ behavior has changed.  Read this thread on Bugzilla for details: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1084004

Comment: Do you still want this for Firefox 31, or have you moved on to Firefox 32.0.1?

Comment: As it turned out, it was only a few more minutes to make it work in 31.0 also. At least it should work, just not tested due to not wanting to downgrade to 31.0 from 32.0.1.

Comment: BTW: From what version did you upgrade to 31.0?  I ask because at first look this does not appear to have changed between at least FF29.0.1 to 31.0.

Comment: It may have been as early as FF26 but I'm not sure though.  I remember it was a somewhat large jump because Linux doesn't have an option to update automatically so I usually get a few versions behind.  My distro at home needs updating badly enough that I'm stuck on FF20 until then (unless I install from source and I'm too lazy).  It doesn't even have the option of putting the toolbox on the right edge.  I can't remember where the option itself was either but it's strange that they'd remove something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not missing the option.  The option does not exist.

However, here is a quick-and-dirty extension that does what you want for Firefox 31.0 through 34.0:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/oxt4c5o5vypca85/place-webconsole-object-view-vertical%40makyen.foo.xpi

I tested it on Firefox 31.0, 32.0.1, 32.0.2, 33.0b4 (current beta), and 34.0a2 (Aurora, the current alpha). All of them worked. The file the extension changes, webconsole.xul, has 4 slightly different versions in that range of Firefox releases. One of the changes was between 32.0.1 and 32.0.2.

I had another extension for which I was already working on a similar set of compatibility and testing and then Mozilla released FF 32.0.2 today. Leaving this solution as only compatible for 31.0-32.0.1 just didn't sit well with me, so I did the mods to give it the wider compatibility range.

In 34.0a2 the stock behavior of this part of the webconsole is a bit different.  The object view automatically shifts from vertical to horizontal depending on how wide the devtools sidebar is. Visually, this is similar to how the inspector behaves in 31.0 (and later). The above extension, when installed on 34.0b, will lock it in the vertical position.  Personally, I really don't like the auto-choosing of vertical/horizontal. I would want a control and be able to lock it the way *I* want it when *I* am viewing it. This is not supposed to be a glitzy wiz-bang UI thing to get the masses interested. This is a: I want to get my work done now and I want it my way because that's how I work fastest/best. Sorry, I got up on my soapbox there a bit.

[image: Screenshot with extension installed in Firefox 32.0.1]

Comment: I'm not at my work computer now so I'll have to wait to test, looks perfect though.  Screenshot is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It worked in FF31 with no hiccups, will be updating to 32 soon-ish.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it.  I hope it helps.  Just FYI: Awarding the bounty is a separate step from accepting the answer. The directions from the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) say: "You can award a bounty by clicking on the respective button below the upvote/downvote interface." The reputation has already been removed form your account.  If not awarded, it just disappears.

Comment: And thank you. In case you are not informed when an answer is modified: I updated the extension with broader compatibility wrt. Firefox releases 31.0 through at least 34.0b4 instead of just 31.0 through 32.0.1. In part because Mozilla released 32.0.2 today which would have been incompatible.

Comment: I just updated to v33 and it broke.  Do you have a link to the version that supports <= v34?  Also I filed a feature request at Bugzilla.  IMHO they should be maintaining this, not you.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1084004

Comment: Never mind, I didn't re-download the new version.  I see you updated the link and forgot to check that.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  I had just re-verified that it was working in FF33 and was writing a comment asking if you had downloaded it again.  Just FYI: stock FF34 adds the feature that the layout is auto-switched based on the width to which you resize the console sidebar. This extension still works to force it to the A over B layout in FF34. Auto layout is a glossy feature which looks OK, but not having the ability for the user to force a specific layout is a bad idea from a UI point of view, particularly in a developer tool like this.

Answer (score 2):

This was added in Firefox 34, now in Beta. It is *not* in Firefox 33, the current release.

If you have the toolbox docked to the side, the Object Viewer pane will automatically drop to the bottom if the toolbox gets too narrow, see this gif for a visual example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the icon that has a rectangle at the bottom. In your case (Where the yellow arrow points):

[image: Toggle Mode]

Comment: MaKR is asking about the sub-sidebar Object view (the part highlighted in red), not the entire devtools sidebar.